# Can a short-sighted person see a target 'better' than someone with no impediment, if target is very close?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision, biology

Can a short-sighted person with no corrective appliance see an object more clearly than a person with no impediment, if the object is at an optimal distance for them (i.e. closer than the unimpaired person could tolerate)?

My thinking is that the short-sighted person can tolerate the object being closer, therefore has an advantage in the sense they will be absorbing more 'photonic information' (!?) about the object?

I was going to ask on healthcare.stackexchange but feels a bit more advanced, hence hope it's okay to ask as physics question.

Comment: Biology.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I have +10 diopter nearsightedness. My focus distance ranges between 2 and 2.5 inches. I take my glasses off to do extreme closeup detail work. I can use only one eye at a time at this distance since 2" is too close to point both eyes at the same spot.

The ability to get this close is the **only** positive aspect of this much nearsightedness :-). Had I been born 200 years ago I'd probably have made a good watchmaker.

If you want to experience this yourself, buy the strongest reading glasses you can find, probably +3.5.

Comment: To put this in more general terms we say that the "near point" of a near-sighted person is closer than that of a nominally focusing or far-sighted person (at least for the same age range).